# Instead of JSON response to POST request, what are my options for React?

Tags: json, node.js, reactjs, post, ejs

Client-side I have a `<form method="POST" action="/register">` which makes an SQL query.

Server-side I have this:

```
router.post('/register', function (req, res, next) {
    // code [...]
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        res.render('register', {
           title: 'Registration Error',
           errors: errors.mapped()
        });
    }
}
```

OK cool, with ejs I have managed to work with the incoming variable `errors` which is invisible (see next sentence) but my goal is to switch to React. Now, instead of the variable `errors` I have managed to send a json, but this json appears in the Developer Tools -> Network tab.

I've noticed that third party websites are using POST method with React and I don't see any json in the network tab, so it's either hidden or they use a different method.

Instead of JSON response to POST request, what are my options for React (or if I can hide it)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle the response of a (POST) request in React (or JavaScript) you'll need to send the request via `fetch` or `xhr`.

Fetch: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

XHR: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: The issue is that I don't want the JSON response to appear in the Developer Tools -> Network tab.

Comment: Thats unavoidable as far as I'm aware. If the server responds with it, dev tools will show it.